# How to define an application-level global method to be used anywhere in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, methods, global

I have a method `current_org` that's defined simply as:

```
def current_org
  Organization.find_by(subdomain: Apartment::Tenant.current)
end
```

It's always the same, whether it's in a view, controller, a model, or even a service. Since the current tenant is derived from the database connection, I shouldn't have to worry about it being properly scoped. And I find myself using it everywhere.

What's the best way to define a global method in Rails so I can just call `current_org` from anywhere? Currently my best solution is defining a module in `/lib` and calling it with `CustomHelperMethods.current_org`. But I'm looking for something a little cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I'd put it as a class method in an `Organiation` model or create a special service/class that fetches it.

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  def self.current_org
    find_by(subdomain: Apartment::Tenant.current)
  end 
end
```

or

```
# e.g. in app/services/
class CurrentOrganization
  def self.current_org
    Organization.find_by(subdomain: Apartment::Tenant.current)
  end 
end
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to define `current_org` in a global application context so I can just call `current_org`, rather than having to prepend a model or service object to the method.

Comment: You can define it in any file, just be sure it's manually required, as this method won't be autoloaded using constant resolution. You can e.g. define it in a initializer (`config/intializers/`), but I'd strongly recommend keeping it in a module/class scope.

Comment: I was hoping I'd find arguments against using it outside of a module. What are your reasons for not using it in a global application context?

Comment: 1. It uses rails constant loading mechanism, so it will be reloaded when the code changes (as other constatnts). 2. It's easier to test and mock if it's not an object/class. 3. It will be easier to understand and track in the future. 4. If any object defines a method with the same name, the global one will be hidden.

Comment: Plus if you use a module you can just mix it into ApplicationController, the view context and ApplicationModel which is equates to pretty much everywhere in a rails app besides configuration.